# How to use hash table to determine if there are two points in an array have slope k

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable, pseudocode

How to use hash table to find specific slope for points in an array to improve time complexity?

Comment: Does the match with `k` need to be exact?  If not, how close is good enough?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is simply to index the points by the y values with the slope expectation effectively removed: i.e. "standardised y" y' = y - x * slope

Put another way, if you draw a line at slope k from two or more points back to the same point on the y axis (where x = 0), they'll form a solution set.

Note that you may get actual or approximate (due to rounding) matches on y' values, so should:

- use a hash table that supports duplicate keys (e.g. C++'s `unordered_multimap`) or - clumsier - map from y' to a container of x,y points, and
- use whatever heuristic you deem best for extremely close y' values should be treated as equal (or otherwise, do some check/filtering on the raw x,y coordinates when y's are close/equal)

Pseudo-code:

```
for x,y in points
    y' = y - x * slope
    hash_multimap.insert(key=y', value=(x, y))
traverse hash_multimap
    solution set includes any same-y'-key entries AND
        values so close they're presumed rounding errors
        e.g. one/two/a-few applications of
        std::next_after(y', MAX_DOUBLE) to find nearest
        representable double values (separate O(1) lookups);
        values can be erased or marked invalid once outputted
```

Comment: Ah of course. A shear transformation makes a lot more sense than a rotation. Upvoting this, and I think I'm going to delete my answer in favour of yours.